# Mysterious SQL query running regularly on Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, entity-framework, orm

We have a production SQL Server running on Azure, as the data storage for an endpoint of a console app used by ~50 users.
Around every 4 hours, we see a spike in resource usages (DTU).

After finding the most resource consuming queries, via:

```
sys.dm_exec_query_stats, sys.dm_exec_cached_plans, and sys.dm_exec_sql_text
```

We noticed 2 regular queries that runs **for each table** on our database:

```
SELECT TOP 131072 
    ISNULL(AVG(CAST(ISNULL(DATALENGTH([COLUMN_1]), 0) AS FLOAT)), 0),
    ISNULL(AVG(CAST(ISNULL(DATALENGTH([COLUMN_2]), 0) AS FLOAT)), 0),
    ISNULL(AVG(CAST(ISNULL(DATALENGTH([COLUMN_3]), 0) AS FLOAT)), 0),
    ISNULL(AVG(CAST(ISNULL(DATALENGTH([COLUMN_N]), 0) AS FLOAT)), 0)
FROM [dbo].[MY_TABLE] 
TABLESAMPLE (100 percent)
```

and

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    ISNULL(AVG(CAST(ISNULL(DATALENGTH([COLUMN_1]), 0) AS FLOAT)), 0),
    ISNULL(AVG(CAST(ISNULL(DATALENGTH([COLUMN_2]), 0) AS FLOAT)), 0),
    ISNULL(AVG(CAST(ISNULL(DATALENGTH([COLUMN_3]), 0) AS FLOAT)), 0),
    ISNULL(AVG(CAST(ISNULL(DATALENGTH([COLUMN_N]), 0) AS FLOAT)), 0)
FROM [dbo].[MY_TABLE]
```

- Notice the **131072** (= **2^17**) and "**TABLESAMPLE (100 percent)**" in the first query.
- Also, both queries are executed the exact number of times, for each table.

Those are valid queries, showing the average bytes consumed by each column.

We want to prevent these spikes, but we can't find the source.
Any ideas are welcome.

We tried to find the source of the execution, without luck.
Also searched our codebase & the web for "131072", "TABLESAMPLE" and "ISNULL(AVG(CAST(ISNULL(DATALENGTH", without any luck.

We checked any automatic performance tuning on Azure for the database: there was none.
We use Entity framework for the ORM.

This is the query we used, to find the most "expensive" queries (source unknown):

```
SELECT TOP 25 
            DB_NAME(st.dbid) DatabaseName,
            SUBSTRING(text, 
            CASE WHEN statement_start_offset = 0 OR statement_start_offset IS NULL  THEN 1  ELSE statement_start_offset/2 + 1 END, 
            CASE WHEN statement_end_offset = 0 OR statement_end_offset = -1   OR statement_end_offset IS NULL  THEN LEN(text)  ELSE statement_end_offset/2 END - 
            CASE WHEN statement_start_offset = 0  OR statement_start_offset IS NULL THEN 1   ELSE statement_start_offset/2  END + 1)  AS [Query],
            cp.usecounts AS [ExecCount],
            CAST(qs.total_elapsed_time / (1000000.00 * usecounts) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AverageDuration,
            qs.last_execution_time LastExec,
            DATEDIFF(SECOND, qs.last_execution_time, getdate()) AS LastExecSecsAgo,
            qs.total_worker_time    AS CpuTime,
            qs.total_elapsed_time   AS ElapsedTime,
            qs.total_logical_reads  AS LogicalReads,
            qs.total_logical_writes AS LogicalWrites,
            qs.total_physical_reads AS PhysicalReads
FROM        sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs  
JOIN        sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp on qs.plan_handle = cp.plan_handle 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st
ORDER BY    qs.total_elapsed_time DESC,
            qs.total_worker_time DESC, 
            qs.total_logical_reads DESC
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: If it's be guessing, it sounds like something that gathers database statistics.  Does anything of these queries correspond to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-statistics ? Especially   STATS_DATE(st.[object_id],st.[stats_id]) part

Comment: Unfortunately there's no reference to "stats". Only these 2 queries.

Comment: 131072 is a magic number used as threshold for batchmode on row storage so that might be the motivation for using that particular number. If it runs on a regular schedule can you catch it in the act and see the user/app name etc?

Comment: Well, I couldn't find a way to intercept and get the app details. I'm still trying to, but didn't succeed so far.

Comment: Can you run a trace or extended event session that tracks executed sql? Since it's every 4 hours, you should be able to time it just about right, or just run something like this for a while: `select *
into #t
from sys.dm_exec_requests r
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) h
where 1 = 0

while 1 = 1
insert into #t
select *
from sys.dm_exec_requests r
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) h
where h.text like '%TABLESAMPLE%'
and r.session_id <> @@SPID`

Comment: Those queries look like part of Azure performance monitoring statistics. It will periodically probe table query performance.  You might check what monitoring you have enabled on the database. Like logging, the more granular you get, especially when attempting to identify performance issues, the more it can end up having a negative impact on performance, creating a feedback loop. :)  Personally, DB performance metrics is something I like to set up and activate over specific days/hours when I can digest the findings rather than leave running continuously.